# Pasting data in openoffice Calc

Tags: copy-paste, openoffice-calc

I want to paste data in Openoffice Calc but it doesn't seem to work.

The example with the first row (of 124 rows), this is the data in a .dat-file:

```
   0.592    0.349    1.333    0.617
```

When I want to insert it in openoffice (either through copy + paste or open and then select the .dat-file) I got a screen with several options to paste the data: [screenshot openoffice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhPq3.png). There I selected that a space marks as separation (to put the data in four columns and not in 1).
When I press 'OK', all the zeros and commas disappear: [screenshot openoffice 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlorP.png).
Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Does OpenOffice (or your whole computer) believe that it is in a locale where the thousands’ separator is `.` (period) and the decimal point is `,` (comma)?  That would cause it to interpret “`2.013`” as the current year, rather than a number slightly more than two.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your values are simply multiplied by one thousand.

You could just divide them all by one thousand again.

Comment: Yeah, but what causes the problem?